# How to get current component name in vue js 3.0

Tags: vuejs3

I can get component name in vue js 2 by: this.$options.name. How to get it in vue js 3?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get component name at runtime like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {getCurrentInstance} from 'vue'

const componentName = getCurrentInstance()?.type.__name
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it using: this.$parent.componentName.

```
<script lang="ts">
import {Options, Vue} from 'vue-class-component';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';
import {Prop} from "vue-property-decorator";
import {Product} from "@/store/models";

@Options({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('init', this.$parent.componentName + ' mounted')
  },
  emits: ['init']
})
export default class Home extends Vue {

  @Prop(Array) private readonly products!: Product[];

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Options API** (IndexPageOptions.vue)

```html
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'IndexPageOptions',
      // created
      created () {
        console.log(this.$options.name + ': created')
      },
      mounted () {
        console.log(this.$options.name + ': mounted')
      }
    }
    </script>
```

**Composition API** (IndexPageComposition.vue)

```html
    <script>
    // Imports
    import { defineComponent, onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
       
    export default defineComponent({
      name: 'IndexPageComposition',
      setup () {        
        // Created
        console.log(getCurrentInstance().type.name + ': created')
    
        onMounted(() => {
          console.log(getCurrentInstance().type.name + ': onMounted')
        })
      }
    })
    </script>
```

**Script Setup** (IndexPageScriptSetup.vue)

```html
    <script setup>
    import { onMounted, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
    // Created
    console.log(getCurrentInstance().type.__name + ': created')
    
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(getCurrentInstance().type.__name + ': onMounted')
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me...

This works (called from inside the component you want the name of):

```
console.log(this.$.type.name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
```

In setup,

```
const router = useRouter();
const componentName  = router.currentRoute.value.name;
```

Comment: It get router name instead component name

Comment: Same for me ...